# Web-scraping - show all hidden nodes in HTML - no path found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Update: I made some mistake with Xpath. Actually, all the data were already there in the HTML. Sorry for this.

I am trying to get all the data from a website; however, I can't scrape all the data as some nodes are hidden. Although all results are displayed on the website (a rather long list), only a handful amount of nodes are displayed when I inspect the website element. Hence, I can only scrape these visible nodes.

hidden nodes in html:

[image: hidden nodes in html]

I have done an extensive search and most of the solutions suggest to do dynamic clicking to expand the website in order to scrape; however, there is no such button on the website. They display everything, but their HTML does not.

My question is there is any way to automatically expand these hidden nodes in the website's HTML code, so I can scrape them.

Comment: Most likely, they are loaded dynamically using javascript. You will need further investigation on how they are loaded before trying to scrap the website.

Comment: Your question doesn’t make sense. If all of the data is visible on the page, then it must be in the DOM. The browser will only render nodes that actually exist in the DOM. You’ll need to provide much, much more information—a specific example, really, including the URL of the page, the complete source of the script you’ve tried, and the complete output you see when executing that script.

Comment: @Ian, you are right. Just realize that I made a mistake with my xpath so my code did not retrieve all the data I wanted. The data was there already. Sorry for this silly question guys, I am still new :|

Answer (score 0):

In my case the hidden nodes were not all there on the page.
They would appear only if scrolling down till the bottom of the html, and only then the page would load them.
What worked for me was:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
for i in range(5): # <-- this is the number of times you want to scroll down
    # use the js path of the last elem on your page
    last_elem = "#my-div-id > ul > li:last-child" 
    # scroll the page up to the last elem
    scroll = "document.querySelector(\'" + last_elem + "\').scrollIntoView();" 
    browser.execute_script(scroll) # execute the js scroll
    time.sleep(3) # <-- let some time for the page to load

# example of how to get html data via js in python    
# let's get all a.href through javascript
js_script = '''\
var links = []
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => links.push(a.href));
return links;
'''
links = browser.execute_script(js_script)
```